# How do I add a form to Joomla that allows a registered user to add a contact?

Tags: php, joomla, web

I'm building a website where registered users will be able to add their own contact details.  So I need a form that allows them to enter the details and submit them to the database.

It also be useful if new database entries were flagged somehow for validation by an administrator.

The core Joomla contacts component doesn't seem to have this functionality.

I'm using Joomla 2.5.

How would I achieve this?

UPDATE: I'm looking for an existing solution to this problem without having to resort to coding it myself.

Comment: are you expecting some one else to write it for you?

Comment: No.  I'm not sure why you would ask that?  There are so many extensions available for Joomla.  I am wondering if there is any easy way to achieve this without doing any coding (that is why I am using Joomla).

Answer (score 1):

Joomla 2.5 includes a plugin (disabled by default) that allows you to add extra contact fields to the User registration and profile edit pages.

Go into your Plugin Manager and look for the 'User - Profile' plugin.

It may allow you to do what you need without resorting to a 3rd party extension.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found any existing solution to my problem (although there are many extensions I haven't looked at).

I did find an excellent tutorial that I worked through to learn how to code my own extensions:

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component_-_Part_1